# Order an array of objects by using a different sort array

Tags: php, sorting

I'm a little stuck with some array sorting, maybe someone can help me out?

Given these two arrays:

```
$sortOrder = array(12, 20, 4);

$data = array(
    (object)array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Tom' 
    ),
    (object)array(
        'id' => 12,
        'name' => 'Bob' 
    ),
    (object)array(
        'id' => 20,
        'name' => 'Max' 
    ) 
)
```

I want to sort `$data` by the id order specified in `$sortOrder`.

So after sorting I want $data to be like this:

```
$data = array(
    (object)array(
        'id' => 12,
        'name' => 'Bob' 
    ),
    (object)array(
        'id' => 20,
        'name' => 'Max' 
    ), 
    (object)array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Tom' 
    ),
)
```

How would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`usort`](http://www.php.net/usort) will help you.

```
usort($data, function ($a, $b) use ($sortOrder) {
   $pos1 = array_search($a->id, $sortOrder);
   $pos2 = array_search($b->id, $sortOrder);

   return ($pos1 === $pos2) ? 0 : ($pos1 < $pos2 ? -1 : 1);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the most elegant approach.

Answer (score 2):

please try this. it will print as your expected output.

```
  $sortOrder = array(12, 20, 4);

 $data = array(
    array(
        'id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Tom' 
   ),
  array(
         'id' => 12,
         'name' => 'Bob' 
     ),
     array(
         'id' => 20,
         'name' => 'Max' 
     ) 
 );

 $sortedArray = array();
 foreach($sortOrder as $id) 
 {
     foreach($data as $_data)
     {
         if($_data["id"] == $id)
         {
             $sortedArray[] = $_data;
             break;
         }
     }
 }

 print_r($sortedArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try use sort and foreach to made it?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php